# Delay Container Start Until other Container in pod is Started

Tags: kubernetes

I am working on a use case where sidecar container runs a shell script continuously  on changes directory permission of main container.
I want to Start side container only after Main Container in pod is ready .

I was looking at Init Containers and what I could see is init containers are good candidate when we have inter-pod dependency (pod A starts only after Pod B has started/healthy).

In my case I need container B to start only after Container A is started in the same Pod.

Deployment.yaml for refrence

```
     containers:
    - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
   - name: container2
      image: some-repo
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any K8s native feature or hook that satisfies the use case you describe.

I would solve it like this:

Run your sidecar container within the same Pod as a regular container and get it to executes a script that pings the readiness endpoint of your application container before proceeding to check directory permissions.

Comment: Thanks , I will have to do the same via a bash script , I was looking for any k8s feature which could provide me something , but your suggestion makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Marko Lukša wrote a blog post (https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/delaying-application-start-until-sidecar-is-ready-2ec2d21a7b74) on this subject.

You can write a bit of script that runs on container A and waits until it's "officially ready" before it exits. Attaching that command to container A's post-start lifecycle phase will prevent subsequent containers in the pod from starting until it completes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: container-a-starts-first
spec:
  containers:
  - name: containerA
    image: container-a
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
          - /bin/wait-until-ready.sh
  - name: containerB
    image: container-b
```