# Pod getting restarted many times when using sidecar container

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm

I'm deploying a sidecar container in a kubernetes deployment.

The issue is that the pod sometimes is getting restarted many times because the main container (container1) is not ready at all.

The deployment is similar to this one but the sidecar container cannot reach propertly the container1 when this one is not ready. I think that's the reason why the pod is getting restarted many times

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: webserver
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: shared-logs
      emptyDir: {}

  containers:
    - name: container1
      image: image1
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /var/log/nginx

    - name: sidecar-container
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh","-c","while true; do cat /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log; sleep 30; done"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /var/log/nginx
```

My question is simple. Is there any way to make busy-box container to wait for container1 until is ready?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delay Container Start Until other Container in pod is Started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909314/delay-container-start-until-other-container-in-pod-is-started)

Comment: Well, I don't want to do any modificarmtion in my script. I would like just do any modifkcation into the kubernetes file.

Comment: Well, life would be so easier if we all got what we wanted :)
As mentioned in that SO question, I too am not aware of any K8s native feature or hook that satisfies the use case you describe. So, unless someone knows one (and answers it over here) your only option would be to change your script. Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried using [probes](https://loft.sh/blog/kubernetes-probes-startup-liveness-readiness/)? 
You can configure the sidecar container to use the liveliness and readiness probe with the check mechanisms described [here](https://loft.sh/blog/kubernetes-probes-startup-liveness-readiness/).

Comment: I’d really appreciate if you can post an example that is working with a sidecar container. I have never worked with probes before. Basically i want to delay the sidecar container till the main one is ready.

Comment: Since you haven't marked the lifecycle of the second container as `sidecar` I'm assuming you're running a multi-container pod in a sidecar pattern. Since you're doing that I'd suggest taking a look at [this](https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/delaying-application-start-until-sidecar-is-ready-2ec2d21a7b74) it simplifies the solution. Hope this helps!

Comment: The two containers don't seem to be directly communicating except through the shared filesystem; it's not obvious to me that the second container could cause the first one to exit.  Do you know why the pod is restarting?

Comment: After adding a sleep that waits for the main container in the program executed in the sidecar container the issue is gone.

Comment: @ X T would you put your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, to resolve it faster I have just included a sleep before executing the code so I can give enought time to the main container to be ready.

```
time.Sleep(8 * time.Second)
```

That's not the best solution but resolves the issue.